# Monitor doesn't display despite being sort of detected on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

My external monitor does not display after being connected with HDMI to my Samsung Ativ Book 4. The monitor itself indicates that it isn't receiving a signal, having a 'yellow light' instead of the 'blue light' that it shows when displaying a picture.

Display settings are aware that the monitor is connected, and I can switch display interface such that it theoretically is showing extend or duplicate or just 1 or 2, but it only ever shows on 1. I had to reset display configuration via registry after setting it to show only on 2. The display interface in settings shows as below.

[image]

Comment: Try a different monitor to ensure the computer is working correctly and if so replace the monitor

Comment: Are you sure the monitor is getting the correct resolution? Are your graphics drivers up to date?

Comment: I've tested two monitors and two different hdmi cords

Comment: it's a problem with the computer, be it hardware or software